# Applying DATABASE_OPTIONS when testing Django project (or make it to use InnoDB for MySQL)

Tags: mysql, django, testing, innodb, django-testing

As the title says, I want to apply DATABASE_OPTIONS settings when I run my tests via `./manage.py test`. In `django/db/backends/creation.py`, it does not consider this option at all in both `create_test_db()` and `_create_test_db()`.

This breaks a test with a view that uses `transaction.rollback` function with InnoDB. It seems that test databases are not created with InnoDB storage engine.

Is there any workaround or fix to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason by myself. I have to use TransactionTestCase instead of normal TestCase base class. [See the documentation.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround might be to set the default storage engine on your server to InnoDB.

in my.cnf:

```
set default_storage_engine=InnoDB
```

That should work unless django is explicitly picking MyISAM.

Comment: Yes, I'd already applied this, but for testcases, it did not help. See my self-answer below. :)